# How to use Flyway configuration to handle multiple databases

Tags: java, database, maven, database-migration, flyway

we have a java application configured with maven that uses multiple databases. It is one app - many schemas.

I've configured flyway, tested and it works well but my config is only for one database.

Here is my pom.xml tested with one schema:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Flyway plugin configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/argentina</url>
                    <user>test</user>
                <password>test</password>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.21</version>
            </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
              <!-- alllll my dependency list -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- DB dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Update: by using the answer provided now I have the following pom.xml configured with 2 schemas.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>argentina</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase> <!--whatever phase you need-->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/argentina</url>
                            <user>test</user>
                            <password>test</password>
                            <locations>
                                <location>
                                    filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration                                  
                                </location>
                            </locations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>brazil</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase> <!--whatever phase you need-->
                        <goals>
                            <goal>migrate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brazil</url>
                            <user>test</user>
                            <password>test</password>
                            <locations>
                                <location>
                                    filesystem:src/main/resources/test2/sql
                                </location>
                            </locations>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.21</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

  <dependencies>
        ...
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I execute flyway operations but none worked, here is the error I got:

```
[INFO] Copying 5 resources
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] [flyway:migrate {execution: argentina}]
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/argentina (MySQL 5.5)
[INFO] Validated 4 migrations (execution time 00:00.006s)
[INFO] Current version of schema `argentina`: 45678
[INFO] Schema `argentina` is up to date. No migration necessary.
[INFO] [flyway:migrate {execution: brazil}]
[INFO] Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/brazil (MySQL 5.5)
[INFO] Validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.003s)
[INFO] Current version of schema `brazil`: 1
[INFO] Schema `brazil` is up to date. No migration necessary.
[INFO] [flyway:migrate {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: DataSource not set! Check your configuration!
```

The database configuration is ok. Also I checked the schemas are ok What I am missing?

UPDATE: I removed from the command line flyway: and it worked well. Thanks `Jk1`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify multiple executions for a single plugin with different configurations:

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>first-execution</id>
            <phase>compile</phase> <!--whatever phase you need-->
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema2</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>root</password>
                <locations>
                    <location>
                        filesystem:/path/to/migrations/folder
                    </location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>second-execution</id>
            <phase>compile</phase> <!--whatever phase you need-->
            <goals>
                <goal>migrate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema1</url>
                <user>root</user>
                <password>root</password>
                <locations>
                    <location>
                        filesystem:/path/to/other/migrations/folder
                    </location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

You can use 'location' property to define migrations you want to run for each schema, just like it's done in example above. The location type is determined by its prefix. Unprefixed locations or locations starting with classpath: point to a package on the classpath and may contain both sql and java-based migrations. Locations starting with filesystem: point to a directory on the filesystem and may only contain sql migrations.

Comment: Thanks Jk1, I'll test this asap and confirm it

Comment: How do we handle migrations for this? I mean how can I set migrations to run on its specific schema?

Comment: I tried you conf but haven't worked. I got this maven error:
[INFO] 'run' was specified in an execution, but not found in the plugin

Comment: My bad, accidentaly included extra tag in configuration section. Please check the updated answer. This version works ok on my machine and also addresses your first question regarding migrations specific for the particular schema.

Comment: I tried you configuration but think it still needs something else related to datasources. I got the error "DataSource not set! Check your configuration!". I've updated the question with newer details. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: I tried again. The problem was that I was using maven <execution> plugin and also mvn compile flyway:info. I had to remove maven command line and it worked fine. Thanks you rock. I updated the post with more details for everyone.

Comment: To run goals against the individual executions you would do something like "mvn flyway:info@first-execution"