# How do I use the Flyway command-line client and flyway.conf to migrate multiple databases?

Tags: sql-server, flyway

I started using flyway and its easy , but i only tried it with one Database. 
setting flyway.url to that database
Using flyway migrate from command line to execute all the scripts.
This is the current Setting.

flyway.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

## Jdbc url to use to connect to the database

flyway.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://'databaseName'

## User to use to connect to the database (default: <>)

flyway.user=user

## Password to use to connect to the database (default: <>)

flyway.password=user

but i am having problem with multiple databases and scripts for each DB, 
how can i set flyway to migrate data to all the databases ? 
run separate schema for each ? 
 can i add multiple databases info to the config file?
what should i set my flyway.url to in the properties file

Comment: I asked a similar question but my conf was for maven plugin. You can take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545657/how-to-use-flyway-configuration-to-handle-multiple-databases

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using the command-line client. It has a -configFile option that lets you choose which config file to use. Simply use one config file per DB and you should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the command-line client. It has a -configFile option that lets you choose which config file to use. Simply use one config file per database and you should be ok.

For example, if you have Flyway installed in a folder called **c:/Flyway**:

- Copy your **conf/flyway.conf** file to a file called **conf/prod.conf**.
- Open it and update the username, password, and url properties, e.g:

  `flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://dbinstance.eu.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/myapp`
- Then run in a command prompt (shell):

  `flyway -configFile=c:/flyway/conf/prod.conf migrate`

Answer (score 0):

There is actually useful documentation on the topic:
https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/configuration-files-224003079.html

And the configuration property of the CLI is now called `-configFiles` and allows specifying multiple entries.

E.g. create a file per database with connection properties like

`flyway-local.conf:`

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foo
flyway.username=bar
flyway.password=baz
```

And reference it with
`./flyway -configFiles=flyway-local.conf migrate`