# Try to use flyway for multiple DB instances

Tags: java, maven, execution, flyway

Running the Maven `flyway-plugin`

```
mvn flyway:migrate
```

with this configuration:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3</version>
      <configuration>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
        <user>root</user>
        <password>root</password>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

I try to create number of executions like in this solution:
[How to use Flyway configuration to handle multiple databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545657/how-to-use-flyway-configuration-to-handle-multiple-databases)

Start from one execution:

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
      <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>migrate-database</id>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>migrate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema2?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</url>
            <user>root</user>
            <password>root</password>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

See exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:4.0.3:migrate (default-cli) on project UrbanLife: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password! -> [Help 1]
```

Looks like flyway can't see configuration inside 
(Interesting that, in link, I mentioned before, it works)

Please help to create flyway multyDB integration via maven.

Comment: Two answers below helped me. Now I use next command: 
 mvn flyway:migrate@migrate-MAINdatabase  flyway:migrate@migrate-TESTdatabase

Comment: @markdsievers why you removed phrases about console from my question? It's more understandable for novice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple (or just one) `<execution>` in your maven plugin configuration and are attempting to run a specific execution from the command line you need to specify the execution by the execution `id` like so in your case

```
mvn flyway:migrate@migrate-database
```

see also: [How to execute maven plugin execution directly from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3166538/how-to-execute-maven-plugin-execution-directly-from-command-line)

Lastly, if you want a specific execution to be the default, you can give it the execution id of `default-cli` as explained in [these maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html). Then you can simply run `mvn flyway:migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

The FQN of the driver is incorrect, it should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or you could also simply remove it as it will be auto-detected from the URL.

You will also need to add the driver as dependency of your plugin by adding

```
<plugin>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```